# Using fold_left to search for an element in OCaml

Tags: list, ocaml

I'm wondering how can I build a function in Ocaml that uses `List.fold_left` to find out if an element exists in a list.
Example:

```
exists 3 [1;2;3;4;5] 
=> true
```

The type of this function is: `a -> bool -> 'a list -> bool`

My idea how to do it is as follows:

```
let exists k l = List.fold_left( fun a x-> a=x) k l
```

but obviously is wrong. Any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: I bet you meant `'a -> 'a list -> bool` as type for the `exits` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after the hints taken by the answers i could be able to improve it more.

Here is my solution

```
let exists' f l =List.fold_left(fun a b->  f b || a  ) false l;;
```

Like this, this function is more abstract and can be used for any predicate f.

Answer (score 6):

```
let exists k l =
    List.fold_left (fun b x -> b || x = k) false l
```

Two comments on @tonio's answer:

- Use `||` instead of superfluous `if ... then true else ...`.
- Use structural equality (`=`) instead of reference equality (`==`) for comparing values.

Moreover, `exists` is available in [List module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html). The built-in function is more efficient since it doesn't have to go through the whole list every time.

Comment: thanks for you correction. Although the aim is to learn  List iterators. indeed List.exists its already developed.

Comment: if you write it as `(fun b x -> b || x = k)`, then you can skip doing the `=` for elements after the first one found. it probably won't make a difference though

Answer (score 5):

You should use something like

```
let exists k l =
    List.fold_left(
      fun a x -> if x == k then true else a)
      false l
;;
```

You have an initial value of `false`, and pass it while iterating over the list. Once the searched element is found, set the value to `true`, and pass it along. If the element in the list is not what you search, pass the value you had as input: it is either the initial `false`, or `true` if the element you search for has already been found.

Comment: Thanks my problem was that!! i mean how to affect a Boolean value, for instance to do the summation is easy , we just need to sum and sum etc... in this case i can see that it works like an variable that can be affected. Thanks